# WordPress Side-Note

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to put footnotes on the side of my page in WordPress, like

```
http://www.grantland.com/story/_/id/6640925/time-lebrondown-part-ii
```

---

Here's my website: http://www.drfus.com/

As you can tell, I edited the CSS and it works. But for me, only in Firefox and Safari. Not Chrome and IE. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of xhtml errors, like a missing closing `</div>` from the wrapper `<div>`that is probably throwing the sidebar out - very common in Wordpress themes - as well as bad nesting inside of `<ul>` elements.

See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  drfus.com  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//drfus.com/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

If you want the vertical position of the footnotes in the sidebar in relation to the text on the entry-content `<div>` - whoch I'm guessing you want to do - one idea is to use some sort of jQuery on document ready to look for the footnote number in the `<div>` and position the sidebar text.